# How to use social stream in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, social-stream

Hello and had problems trying to use this gem would like to know how to fix it add it to my Gemfile

```
gem "social_stream", "~> 2.2.2"
```

When I run "bundle install"
I get this error in response, that I can do? I am a little new.

```
  Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    social_stream (~> 2.2.2) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.1) ruby

    rails (4.0.0)
```

as I can use this gem in Rails 4.0 or Rails version change, whether it is advisable to do so?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I"m currently using a fork, although there do seem to be a few bugs to be resolved.

```
gem 'social_stream', github: 'beder/social_stream'
```

This fork targets 4.0.9

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question two weeks ago.
Unfortunately, Social Stream is not yet ready for use with rails 4.

But the support to change this, is very welcome.

See: https://github.com/ging/social_stream/issues/465