# How to install Social Stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, social-stream

I'm trying to integrate the Social Stream gem with my Rails application. However, it returns a list of dependencies that I already have and states that they are needed. How do I get the gems to be recognized within the gemfile when running `bundle update`?

```
You need to install git to be able to use gems from git repositories. For help
installing git, please refer to GitHub's tutorial at
https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git
```

I have also looked up the webpage at github, but it only explains how to set up git, which I have already done. There is also another error message that states that there are not git files installed in the ruby folder or on the project:

```
C:\Ruby22-x64>gem install social_stream-base
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing social_stream-base:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160128-17192-1djdrcu.rb extconf.rb
The system cannot find the path specified.
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit    http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You  may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config

    extconf failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-   x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.11 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-  mingw32/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.5.11/gem_make.out
```

How do I allow for git to be seen?

Comment: you've run bundle install first right?

Comment: Yes, but it keeps displaying a long error message.

Comment: It also says that I need to install git, which is already installed.

Comment: Well, care to update your question with the long error message, it's kind of relevant, if you can't install it..

Comment: I've uploaded the error message onto the question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so bundle update won't do anything for you, bundle install is what you need to do, but as discovered, there is an error with that. Update will only operate on what has been installed.

I also note that when running 'gem install social_stream-base', when using bundle the correct way is to add gem 'social_stream-base' into your gemfile, and run bundle install. I just add that for completeness.

As per your error message, there is a dependency on Nokogiri. Here is a link to how to get it installed on Windows: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#windows

You will need to get Nokogiri installed, and likely you will face any number of additional issues, which is the norm in my experience when trying to get these things working in Windows. If you try and can't troubleshoot it, then it's back to Stack O.

But the main concern I have is this:

- I noticed that nokogiri-1.5.11 was marked as your version, I thought that was a little old - 2013 infact. I tried checking the install notes of Social Stream (http://social-stream.dit.upm.es/started), they were down, I checked the issues page of the project, and it appears Social Stream is not currently supported in Rails 4. [How to use social stream in rails 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533404/how-to-use-social-stream-in-rails-4-0)

In terms of your git issues, which won't progress you, but for completeness I would refer you to [Can't run bundle update on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746748/cant-run-bundle-update-on-windows) which has various flavours of fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to make my own gem for the social network application that I am building. Since social stream hasn't been built for rails 4.x, I don't think I will use it. Thank you.